# Output multiple collections in single razor table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my viewmodel, i have 4 IEnumberable properties that i need to output into a table.

Each property is corresponds to a column in the table. If you look closely, some cells contain more than one value. What would be an ideal what to output this in my razor view?

I haven't used helpers etc up to this point with asp.net mvc. This table requires a bit more logic than a straight forward @for loop.

Here is what my view model looks like

```
public class FactViewModel
{
    public int AssessmentID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MobilityScore> MobilityScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SocialScore> SocialScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FunctionScore> FunctionScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CognitionScore> CognitionScores { get; set; }
}
```

*Each of these IEnumberable properties have the same field: id, value, label.

[image]

Comment: How about 4 `for` loops which iterates through every collection?

Comment: 4 for loops would easily output each collection, but i'm not sure that is going to get the desired output i'm trying to come up with as that approach would require 4 distinct tables, would it not?

Comment: @MikeHometchko in the previous version of my app, it was more straight forward as every column in a row had only one single value. so i just ran through it as a for loop. basically, i'm struggling with trying to build this output. **1. how do i skip a cell** **2. How can i output 2 fields in a single cell***

Comment: @user1541443 we can't answer how can you output 2 fields in a single cell unless you explain why 2 fields would be output into a single cell. Also clarify what object do the 2 field belong to.

Comment: @DanielImms Ok. the column at the very left is a header which indicates the value of the radio inputs in the current row. Now, within each row, there can be more than one radio or none at all. there is a business requirement to be able to have more than 1 radio input in a single cell, or none at all. does this help?

Comment: @user1541443 how do the radio buttons relate to the different type of scores? You should give a example of some sample data and the generated table you expect.

Comment: @DanielImms you don't see the image i uploaded with the post? I had to blur out the text because the form is patented by a doc. i'm not looking for a completed solution here, was just hoping for maybe a link someone could be me in the direction of to help work through the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another property to your `FactViewModel` that combines all your scores and orders them appropriately. You would need each score type to have a common base type for this to happen, for example `Score`.

```
public class FactViewModel
{
    public int AssessmentID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MobilityScore> MobilityScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SocialScore> SocialScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FunctionScore> FunctionScores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CognitionScore> CognitionScores { get; set; }
    public IENumerable<Score> Scores
    {
        get
        {
            var scores = new List<Score>();
            scores.Add(MobilityScores);
            scores.Add(SocialScores);
            scores.Add(FunctionScores);
            scores.Add(CognitionScores);
            return scores.OrderBy(e => e.Label);
        }
    }
}
```

This means you could just use a regular `@foreach` in razor to output to your table. This hides all the data organisation in the model and not muckying up the view.

```
@foreach (var score in Model.Scores) {
    <tr>
        <td>@score.Id</td>
        <td>@score.Label</td>
        <td>@score.Value</td>
    </td>
}
```

If you use this approach, make sure you subclass `Score`

```
class MobilityScore : Score { }
class SocialScore : Score { }
class FunctionScore : Score { }
class CognitionScore : Score { }

class Score 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that @foreach just out a very long 3 column table?

Comment: @user1541443 Yes, you said 4 at the start but only gave 3 at the end of the question. That doesn't really matter so much, you can just add another `<td>`. Do you think this approach would work?

Answer (score 0):

How are each elements in the set related to one another? If you have multiple items for each component of one assessment does it make sense to make a concatenated object of all the items in each set to display that one thing in the cell? How do the items in each set relate to each other?

I noticed you have radio buttons for each set of items in a column for each assessment ID so if one particular element in MobilityScore has to be selected for something it makes it harder to represent the set as one concatenated item.

You could also (maybe) get away with spanning the row height given the count of the max item out of the 4 collections and for each element in each enumerable then iterate over the max count on each collection and add empty td cells where there are none.